# How to add time value to given select in insert to table

Tags: sql-server

I would like to add one milisecond to column in insert statement. My query is below:

```
INSERT INTO table (
     ID
    ,NAME
    ,DATE_FROM,
) SELECT
      ID
     ,name
     ,DATE_FROM + 1ms

  FROM table
```

Syntax "DATE_FROM + 1ms" is not correct. How can I add 1 ms in this column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
INSERT INTO table (
     ID
    ,NAME
    ,DATE_FROM,
) SELECT
      ID
     ,name
     ,DATEADD(millisecond, 1, DATE_FROM)

  FROM table
```

In this case you can add a millisecond using the DATEADD.

Reference:

- [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DATEADD()`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (
     ID
    ,NAME
    ,DATE_FROM,
) SELECT
      ID
     ,name
     ,DATEADD(MILLISECOND,1,DATE_FROM)
  FROM dbo.YourTable;
```